# Suggestion for implementation of search filter with many2many relationship between two entites

Tags: spring, rest, jpa, criteria, specifications

I want to implement /search rest method that will filter my Product object for the given parameters and return me a pageable set of products that are filtered.

I was reading about Specification interface and Criteria API but i am having difficulties in implementing the solution.

Product entity:

```
@Entity
public class Product implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long productId;

    @NotEmpty(message = "The product name must not be null.")
    private String productName;

    private String productDescription;

    @Min(value = 0, message = "The product price must no be less then zero.")
    private double productPrice;

    @Min(value = 0, message = "The product unit must not be less than zero.")
    private int unitInStock;

    @ManyToMany
    @JoinTable(name = "category_product", joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "product_id"), inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "category_id"))
    private Set<Category> categories = new HashSet<>();
```

As i want the user to be able to search by category name also,bedsides a price range and unitInStock which is separate entity and it is linked with @ManyToMany relationship ,i want to have a method that would look something like:

```
@GetMapping("/search")
    public ResponseEntity<Set<Product>> advancedSearch(@RequestParam(name="category") String categoryName,
                                                       @RequestParam(name="price") double price,
                                                       @RequestParam(name="unitInStock") int unitInStock  ){

    }
```

Category entity:

```
@Entity
public class Category implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long categoryId;

    @NotEmpty(message = "Can not be null")
    private String CategoryName;

    @ManyToMany(mappedBy = "categories")
    @JsonBackReference
    private Set<Product> products = new HashSet<>();
```

Comment: First, Spring provides multiple ways to implement Many-To-Many Relationships like Many To Many with Composite Key class or Many-To-Many with New Entity. It's up to your choice what you chose based on their pros and cons.
Second, When You use JPA, why don't you chose JPQL as your Query Language. This will surely reduce your querying efforts.
Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Create spring repository with method with JPQL query:

```
@Query("select p from Product p left join p.categories c where c.CategoryName like ?1 and p.productPrice=?2 and p.unitInStock=?3")
List<Product> search(String categoryName, double price, int unitInStock)
```